# Limit tcpdump capture files by time and size

Tags: bash, logging, tcpdump

I am having some problems getting tcpdump to log all internet traffic on an interface with the following limitations:

- I would like a new pcap file every hour with time and date tag in the name
- If the pcap file in this hour becomes larger than 100M then create a new pcapfile with the samenametag as before but with a -2 -3 -4 ... suffix.

I am playing around with the following command:

> tcpdump -pni eth0 -s65535 -G 3600 -C 100 -w '/var/log/tcpdump/trace_%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.pcap'

As a result I do get a log file every hour but it does not seem to split the file if it becomes larger than 100.

Does anyone know where I am messing up?
Cheers for the help

Comment: copy version strings from `tcpdump -h` please

Comment: tcpdump version 4.1.1
libpcap version 1.1.1

Comment: works for me with latest versions

Comment: I have been testing also with a new file every 20 seconds and a max file size of 1kb. Is -C 0.001 correct for 1kb?

Comment: You were right. Latest version works for me too.
Cheer for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command should work, maybe there's a bug.

Use tshark (wireshark package) instead:

`tshark -i eth0 -b duration:3600 -b filesize:102400 -s 65535 -w trace.pcap`

> The created filenames are based on the filename given with the -w
>   option, the number of the file and on the creation date and time, e.g.
>   outfile_00001_20050604120117.pcap, outfile_00002_20050604120523.pcap,
>   ...